# Dynamic listbox in JSP

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I have two listboxes on my JSP page. By default the first listbox is filled with database data, When the user selects an item in the 1st listbox, the second will filled accordingly with database data using Ajax. I am new to JSP. I need your help.

I used the below JavaScript code to retrieve the selected value in first listbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript" > 
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#rt_select").click(function() { 
      var option = $('#lstsprintid').val(); 
      alert(option); 
      return option; 
    }); 
  }); 
</script>
```

I am unable to use the value returned from JavaScript in my JSP page. Below is my multiple select listbox where data is coming from db.

```
<p>Select Name :
<select size="3"  id="lstsprintid" multiple="multiple">
<%
while(rs.next())
{
 String name = rs.getString("s_name"); 

 %>
<option value="<%=name %>"><%=name %></option>
<%
}
%>
</select>
```

Which JavaScript code shall I use to get the list of values selected in the above listbox.

```
 <%
 String s1 = request.getParameter("txt_test");
 out.println(s1);
 Statement st1= con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs1=st1.executeQuery("Select sprint_id from sprint where              sprint_name in ("+ s1 +")");
 %>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where exactly are you sturggling? What is your current code?

Comment: It sounds like you should just be reading an introductory Ajax tutorial. I don't understand why you think you should be returning anything from a click event handler function.

Comment: can you please help me out to get a listbox selected value in a string so that i can used in jsp page to further progress

Comment: Use `onchange` with the first list to get the value.

Comment: i got the selected listbox value in the textbox bt i couldnt use the textbox value anywhere in the jsp code.I tried the above step. can u please kindly verify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `onchange` event with the first list and `.selectedIndex` to get its selected value:

```
<script type="text/javascript" > 
   $("#lstsprintid").onchange(function() { 
      var option = $('#lstsprintid').selectedIndex; 
      alert(option); 
      return option;
      // and the use this value to fill the second list
   });  
</script>
```

Comment: I got the selected listbox value in the textbox bt i couldnt use the textbox value anywhere in the jsp code.I tried the above step. can u please kindly verify it

Comment: You have to make an Ajax Request, I really don't have a great idea about it but all you need to do is to use this selected value with your ajax request to get the result of the query, you can take a look at this [tutorial](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/21/complete-ajax-tutorial/).